# jQuery: How do I append an array item in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a weather forecast page for a website.

I am using OpenWeatherMap to retrieve JSON data.

I want to loop through the "weather" array from the JSON, which contains objects that hold weather information.

This is the JSON shown in the console after using console.log (screenshot for readability):

[image]

Here is my jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=57.995221&lon=-6.761395&units=metric&APPID=myAPIkey", function(data){ 

    var currWeather = [data.weather];

    var len = currWeather.length;

    for (i = 0; i > len; i++) {

        $("#weather").append(currWeather[i].main);
        $("#desc").append(currWeather[i].description);
    }

    var clouds = data.clouds.all;
    $("#clouds").append(clouds);

    var temp = data.main.temp;
    $("#temp").append("Temperature: " + temp + "ยบC");

    var humidity = data.main.humidity;
    $("#humidity").append("Humidity: " + humidity + "%");

    var pressure = data.main.pressure;
    $("#pressure").append("Pressure: " + pressure);

    console.log(data);
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="weatherBox">
    <h2>Current Weather</h2>    
    <div id="mainWeather">
        <div id="temp"></div></td>
        <div id="weather"></div>
        <div id="desc"></div>
        <div id="icon"></div>       
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div id="clouds"></div>
    <div id="humidity"></div></td>
    <div id="pressure"></div></td>  
</div>
```

Basically, the only thing that isn't being displayed is the weather information. I have no errors or warnings in the console, am I doing this correctly?

---

Edit: I should add that in the json "weather" array, "0" and "1" are stored as strings. I tried to do:

```
$("#weather").append(currWeather[i.toString()].main);
```

Just to see if it would work. It did not.

Comment: `data.main` is not an object

Comment: Looks like data.weather is already an array, but.... `var currWeather = [data.weather];` - why wrap it in another array? In fact you don't even need currWeather at all, just loop on data.weather until you reach data.weather.length -1 (hint <, not > - you got this the wrong way round too. i starts and 0 and so will never be _greater_ than whatever the length of the array is. And if it was, it wouldn't match any of the array elements.)

Comment: Ah I see. I have solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I found wrong with your code

- You can access a property with dot notation or bracket notation so
  either `data.weather` or `data["weather"]` not `[data.weather]`
- your for loop should declare `i` as a var and it should be `<` the
  length since you start at 0
- The other properties should also be in the loop since they are in an
  obj that is part of the array you are looping.
- you accessed the other properties incorrectly it should be
  `weatherData[i].temp` and not `data.main.temp` the `main` property is
  a string, not an obj so you can't use a property accessor.

And of course you will have to do some additional formatting to make your display look pretty.

```js
var data = {
  weather: [{
    main: "Drizzle",
    description: "A light rain",
    temp: 50,
    humidity: 5,
    pressure: 10
  }, {
    main: "Sunny",
    description: "The sky is blue and so are you",
    temp: 80,
    humidity: 3,
    pressure: 4
  }]
}

var weatherData = data.weather;

var len = weatherData.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  
  var currWeather = weatherData[i];
  //console.log(currWeather);
  $("#weather").append(currWeather.main);
  $("#desc").append(currWeather.description);


  //var clouds = data.clouds.all;
  //$("#clouds").append(clouds);

  var temp = currWeather.temp;
  //console.log(temp)
  $("#temp").append(" Temperature: " + temp + "ยบC");

  var humidity = currWeather.humidity;
  $("#humidity").append(" Humidity: " + humidity + "%");

  var pressure = currWeather.pressure;
  $("#pressure").append(" Pressure: " + pressure);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weatherBox">
  <h2>Current Weather</h2>
  <div id="mainWeather">
    <div id="temp"></div>
    </td>
    <div id="weather"></div>
    <div id="desc"></div>
    <div id="icon"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="clouds"></div>
  <div id="humidity"></div>
  </td>
  <div id="pressure"></div>
  </td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var currWeather = data.weather;
```

You're trying to storing data in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example on jsBin: https://jsbin.com/bijoyoyofo/1/edit?html,js,output

Basically

```
var currWeather = [data.weather];
```

should be

```
var currWeather = data.weather;
```

and

```
for (var i = 0; i > len; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

I also added a paragraph in the div but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your document to include the jQuery $(document).ready() function, using an API key I found on Github for open weather. You can access the weather array from **data.weather**, as you see below. You also had the loop written incorrectly, as you needed the **var i** to be **less than** the length, not greater than. Here is a working sample of your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myAPIkey = 'bd5e378503939ddaee76f12ad7a97608';

  $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=57.995221&lon=-6.761395&units=metric&APPID="+myAPIkey, function(data){ 
    var currWeather = data.weather;

    for (i = 0; i < currWeather.length; i++) {
        $("#weather").append(currWeather[i].main);
        $("#desc").append(currWeather[i].description);
    }
    var clouds = data.clouds.all;
    $("#clouds").append(clouds);

    var temp = data.main.temp;
    $("#temp").append("Temperature: " + temp + "ยบC");

    var humidity = data.main.humidity;
    $("#humidity").append("Humidity: " + humidity + "%");

    var pressure = data.main.pressure;
    $("#pressure").append("Pressure: " + pressure);

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weatherBox">
    <h2>Current Weather</h2>    
    <div id="mainWeather">
        <div id="temp"></div></td>
        <div id="weather"></div>
        <div id="desc"></div>
        <div id="icon"></div>       
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div id="clouds"></div>
    <div id="humidity"></div></td>
    <div id="pressure"></div></td>  
</div>
```